# Why Is jQuery Not Working on Pages Besides the Homepage

Tags: jquery, shopify

I apologize in advance because I can't get the code specifically for these pages. There's a problem and I can't troubleshoot it.

The sub-navigation menu on the homepage works perfectly https://staging-of-thrive-work-wear.myshopify.com/
[image]

Yet, when you go to any other page, the sub-navigation doesn't work. https://staging-of-thrive-work-wear.myshopify.com/products/denim-jean-knee-pad-pants.

I've tried adding jQuery to the page itself through the console tab but it doesn't seem to be working at all. Almost as if jQuery is disabled. But I've never seen or heard of that before.

Again, I'm sorry, I can't get the code just for the sub-navigation because then I wouldn't be able to replicate the error. And I'm not sure if it's jQuery. All I know is that it's not working and any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "add jQuery to the page itself through the console tab". Every page that uses jQuery needs a `<script>` tag that loads it.

Comment: All your pages get an error from this code: `end.onended = function() {
 $(this).pauseVid();
};` because there's no variable `end`.

Comment: Do all your pages contain the same `<script src='sameJsHere.js'></script>` in the `<head>`? Do you have an `addEventListener('load', function(){ })` on all your scripts except your Libraries?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You can view the source, or use whatever you use for editing to copy and paste code. This is important for us to help and for future people who might have the same issue. Your drop-down menu might be using a library that uses jQuery so check to see if you're missing one.

Comment: @Barmar I commented out the `end.onended` function but the sub-navigation still isn't working. And I mean that jQuery isn't loading because I tried to add some jQuery through the console tab and it wasn't working. I also tried adding the jQuery script through the console tab but that wasn't working either. That's what I mean, but I'm not sure if, "jQuery not loading" is an accurate statement from my part. I don't know much about javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the homepage, this code is loaded to perform the sub-menu dropdown:

[dropdown.js](https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0306/1438/8876/t/3/assets/dropdown.js?v=16473668579719561513)

```
$('#navbarDropdown').click(function(event) {
  $('#products-dropdown').toggleClass('show');
});


// PRO
$('#pro').click(function(event) {
  $('#pro-dropdown').toggleClass('show-subnav');
});
// toggles plus/minus sign
$('#pro').click(function(event) {
  $('#pro').toggleClass('active');
});
// closes other tab if open
$('#pro').click(function(event) {
  $('#core-dropdown').removeClass('show-subnav');
});
// removes plus sign if open
$('#pro').click(function(event) {
  $('#core').removeClass('active');
});

// CORE
$('#core').click(function(event) {
$('#core-dropdown').toggleClass('show-subnav');
});
$('#core').click(function(event) {
$('#core').toggleClass('active');
});
$('#core').click(function(event) {
$('#pro-dropdown').removeClass('show-subnav');
});
$('#core').click(function(event) {
$('#pro').removeClass('active');
});
```

But you are not loading it on any other pages, so it isn't working. It isn't a jQuery issue at all, find out how to load that script on all your pages.

Here is a gif showing how you can spot where the event listeners are attached and what files are running them.

**Homepage**

Notice that the file [dropdown.js](https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0306/1438/8876/t/3/assets/dropdown.js?v=16473668579719561513) is loaded here, giving you the functionality you need:

[image: Homepage]

**Any other page**

Notice there is no event listener attached to the sub-menu and the file [bootstrap dropdown.js](https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/js/src/dropdown.js) is loaded but not the necessary [dropdown.js](https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0306/1438/8876/t/3/assets/dropdown.js?v=16473668579719561513):

[image: Other page]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help @DanielSchroederDev but, to be honest with you, I'm not sure why it's not loading on other pages. All the style and script files are loaded through the theme.liquid so I'm not sure why it's only loading on the homepage. Because the dropdown.js is loading on other pages, that's how the first-level subnavigation opens, but then it seems to be overwritten by other javascript because when you click on the second-level subnavigation, there's another onclick function going on that I didn't add. Thanks again for your help.